# Application.FollowHyperlink "https://" & LinkedIn opens two times

Tags: vba, ms-access, linkedin-api

In an Access form I have a field where I put the LinkedIn profile link of an employee.
I made a button next to it to go to that profile on the web.

```
Private Sub ButtonWeb_Click()
Application.FollowHyperlink "https://" & LinkedIn
End Sub
```

Whatever I try I always get the profile opening in two tabs. in Firefox, Opera etc.
When I give any other input in that field e.g. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) it only opens in a single tab.

Does anyone know the linkedin profile link has something of a restriction in it?
Thx for taking some time to help me with this.
Hakim

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem, because I do not understand what you mean by Linked in Profile link.  FollowHyperlink takes a string so if you have a link try something like: Private Sub Command9_Click()
Dim address As String
Dim link As Variant
'address = Application.HyperlinkPart(Me.URL, acAddress)
link = DLookup("URL", "Links", "LinkID = " & Me.LinkID)
address = Application.HyperlinkPart(link, acAddress)
Debug.Print address
FollowHyperlink address
End Sub

Comment: Hi Mazoula,
Thank you for helping. I try to upload a test dbase so you can see what I mean.

Comment: sorry, i am new to this great website. what is the best way to sent/upload an example dbase to show you what i mean?

Comment: Stack overflow does not allow uploading of the database.  try clicking the link in the table and see if the problem starts there.  If so, edit the link and try to include and use the right protocol in the address.  Something like like http://www.amazon.com.

Comment: I uploaded a zip file containing a small example dbase for showing my problem with the link. You can download the file on this page. 
https://www.mediaconsultants.nl/download/dbase-test/
Thx for helping

Answer (score 0):

This is an Issue that has occurred before with linked in.  A work around is to type the link directly in the browser.
Long story short, open your favorite browser from access and navigate to the webpage

```
'if you write the url directly like: 
'www.linkedin.com/in/someuser 
'or https://www.linkedin.com/in/someuser
 Set obj = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
 obj.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", "www.linkedin.com/in/someuser", "", "", 1
   
'However if the url is a variable there is a bug.
dim url as string
url = "www.linkedin.com/in/someuser"
'now the web browser just opens to the default page
obj.ShellExecute "microsoftedge", url, "", "", 1

'it is a parsing problem, to get around it just append an empty string to the url in the call
obj.ShellExecute "microsoftedge", url & "", "", "", 1
```

Comment: Hi Mazoula,
Thank you for helping. Because of Corona I did answer earlier. Sorry.
I tried everything but I am not so experienced in VBA. 
I did this:


Private Sub WebBtn_Click()

    Set obj = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
     Dim url As String
    url = Me.linkedin
    obj.ShellExecute "microsoftedge", url & "", "", "", 1
    
End Sub

It did not work, what did I do wrong?
thx again

Comment: how does it not work?  for instance, if you are landing on the linked in sign in page you don't have authorization.  In that case sign into a linkedin account to get authorization and the link will then go to the correct page.

Comment: Yes, I understand that part but the problem is it says I have to define a vaiable?

Comment: I Have this:

Private Sub WebBtn_Click()
Dim url As String
url = Me.linkedin
Set obj = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
obj.ShellExecute "microsoftedge", url & "", "", "", 1
End Sub

Is this enough?

Comment: you are going to have to do debugging.  The code looks correct.  the error is telling you the problem.  There is a good chance something is misspelled(linkedin), or not in scope( of me.), or needs a type conversion.  that makes me suspicous of me.linkedin.  Debugging in Access VBA is outdated and you may notice that in this case the breakpoints aren't firing where you want and the error isn't being caught where you want.  Here is a long guide to debugging in access if you need to up your game: https://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/vbacode/debug.asp

Comment: Oke, thanx. I'll try to debug the problem.

Comment: When I turn off the Option Explicit in the form your code is working fine and the entire form is still working. Any tips?

Comment: I think this one is on me.  I checked my form code-behind expecting to see Option Explicit and it wasn't there.  This area of VBA felt outdated and buggy when I was working out the solution.  My answer accounts for a bug and the comments I left indicate an alternate approach using Wscript that should have worked and didn't.  While bashing bugs, I abandoned good coding practices in favor of exactly copying online code.  Anyway, the problem is under Option Explicit Objects must be declared.  So first: Dim obj as object  then Set obj = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Comment: Ha Mazoula,
Thx, that was the problem. Now it is all working incl option explicit.