# Access Hyperlink label to an editable GoogleDoc link, does not work

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

In Access 2013, I'm trying to create a label control on a form, so it links to a shared Google doc for editing, but it doesn't get to that page, although the link itself works OK in the browser directly.

Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: The Access web browser control is out of date so google docs will fire off errors.  There is also a small chance there is something wrong with the hyperlink.  Make sure the hyperlink includes the protocol like http://  See here for a work around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72364689/application-followhyperlink-https-linkedin-opens-two-times/72404337#72404337

Comment: It is the label control on a form, which displayes as a hyperlink if setup with a link. I paste the link from the browser, which works OK on another browser tab.

Comment: If the link opens up your default browser (you can tell it is opening the browser) then the access browser isn't the problem.  Check that your default browser is what you think it is and make sure the link address includes the protocol.  Otherwise, you will have to edit the question to provide more details.

Comment: I couldn't manage to overcome the problem. I bypassed it, changing it to a locked textbox and by copying the text link by clicking on it. So it's on the user after that. Thanks anyway.